# Page will not load unless I echo a string at the top of the page

Tags: php

I have a `product.php` page that loads a masterpage and a `productFocus.php` page with additional content. However if I do not echo a string at the top of the `productFocus.php` page, the page will not load. The masterpage always loads as it should.

Beginning the page with just `<?php ?>` does not help.

How can I load the content of `productFocus.php` with the `master.php` in `product.php` without the need of echoing a string at the top of the `productFocus.php` page?

I use JetBeans PhpStorm but XAMPP gives the same result...

**product.php**

```
    <?php
        include_once "db/db.php";
        if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
            $id = $_GET["id"];
            $product = get_product_by_id($id);
            $page_content = 'productFocus.php';
            include('master.php');
        } else {
            header("Location: http://localhost/site/index.php");
            exit();
        }
```

**productFocus.php**

```
<?php echo "." ?> <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< If this is removed the page won't load in the product.php page

<style type="text/css">
    ...
</style>

<div class="product-focus">
    <h3><?php echo $product->name ?></h3>
    <img src="images/products/<?php echo $product->image ?>">
    <div id="description">
        <h4>Productinformatie</h4>
        <p><?php echo $product->description ?></p>
        <h4>Partners</h4>
        <table>
            <?php
                foreach($product->partners_obj as $partner) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href=<?php echo $partner->product_url ?> target="_blank">
                        <img id="partner" src="images/partners/<?php echo $partner->image ?>">
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href=<?php echo $partner->product_url ?> target="_blank">€ <?php echo $partner->product_price ?> </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**master.php**

```
<html>
...
<?php include($page_content);?>
...
</html>
```

Comment: are you sur man ? this is impossible !

Comment: Why do you have that line in the first place? Does it serve a purpose?

Comment: I read somewhere that it's best to start the page with <?php ?> for the php interpreter, but the page still did not load. So I started troubleshooting and the `<?php echo "." ?>` made the page display. It does not serve any purpose other than it fixed my problem for no obvious reason

Comment: Have you tried adding a header?

Comment: Are you using any PHP accelerator?

Comment: @techouse What header should I use?

Comment: @Marek I do not use a PHP accelerator

Comment: When the `<?php echo "." ?>` is there does the page load correctly with the right product?

Comment: @DanielStanley Yes. When I remove the line of code, the content of the `productFocus.php` page does not load. The masterpage loads fine. When I keep the line of code everything loads as it should, but the dot is displayed, which is not a HUGE problem, but I am puzzled why the line is needed...

Comment: It would be useful to create a self containing example exhibiting this behaviour for other people to try. This might be a bug in PHP. Or a misbehaviour in your code that you'll notice while creating the example.

Comment: My past experience with PHP always required me to start a session `<?php session_start(); ?>` I don't think it's the `echo` itself which is making your PHP file work, just that you are doing something in PHP first?

Comment: @DanielStanley When using `session_start();` I get the following warning `Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by master.php`. The content of `productFocus.php` gets displayed, but I am certain it's because of the echoing of the warning

Comment: @David Are you using output buffer functions?

Comment: @Marek I do not use output buffer functions